# Can't build iOS app (flutter) from Android Studio. Works fine on Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, build

I have a flutter app, and I can't run it from Android Studio on an iOS simulator. here is the message I get: after flutter run

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Plus in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              3.6s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           15.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Plus.

I can run it from Xcode without issues.

I tried everything from flutter clean to rebuilding pod but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

try cleaning build folder.

Go to `Build` > `Clean Project`